# Add to dictionary inside a nested object in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document of jobs posted and inside each job I have a fields for the details of the job. I want to keep tract of the applicants who applied to each job .

So at first I have an array of applicants, but I later research and realised that it's not possible to add to the array.
The other option people suggested is that I keep a dictionary of the user reference and a boolean like this [image: Firestore picture]

So now I want to add to that applicants object , I tried but with no success. I will really appreciate it if someone points me to the right direction.

I am also open to other suggestion on how I should handle this problem.

Another option I am thinking is to have a sub collection but then I will have to query for that separately which I am trying to avoid .

Comment: What did you try that didn't work the way you expected? What language are you working with?

Comment: I’m using JavaScript.. React Native

Comment: And what does your code look like that doesn't work the way you expected? It's hard to get a sense of what you're working with.

Comment: So basically what I want to do is if I have another applicant , I will just add it to the applicants object. In the picture there is 6, so if I receive another application I will add it to make it 7